# using capybara, i'm unable to read custom data- attribute from an href

Tags: javascript, jquery, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have some HTML that looks generally like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myclass" data-id="dynamic value"> X </a>
```

it's a delete link and i'm encoding the ID of the item being deleted in the href. 
Then I have some javascript that looks generally like:

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $.ajax({ url: 'correct_url', data: {id: id}, type: 'DELETE'});
}
```

and this all works fine when I'm using the app.

However, I'm trying to test it with capybara (capybara-webkit driver)
and it falls apart:   the DELETE request goes to the server without the id field!  not only is there no value for it,  it just isn't sent.  However the request is made, so it seems the js is being executed, just minus the lines that use `this` and include the extra `data` hash.

any ideas?   It needs to be a variable because there's really a list of things and each one needs its own delete link.  Am I missing a better pattern for accomplishing this whole thing?  Is capybara busted?  thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation of QtWebkit - see https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/427 -  If you're not using the Qt 5.5.1 with capybara-webkit, theres a possibility support may have been added, so you might want to try upgrading.

Comment: I seem to be using Qt 5.2.1.  it feels pretty reasonable/restful to move the id into the url, which works like a champ,  so i'm just going to stick with what's easy.   thanks for your help!!